# Node JS Binding error when trying to use IBM_DB

Tags: node.js

I am getting the below error when trying to use IBM_DB for db2 access.

```
$ node nodetest.js
C:\Users\workspace\nodetest\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:79
    throw e
    ^

Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 47, got 46.
at Error (native)
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:440:18)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
at bindings (C:\Users\workspace\nodetest\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:74:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\workspace\nodetest\node_modules\ibm_db\lib\odbc.js:27:31)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
var http = require("http");
var ibmdb = require("ibm_db");
console.log("Test program to access DB2 sample database");
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8081);
console.log('Server running at 127.0.0.1:8081/');
```

Can someone please help me on this ?

Comment: Could you show us the code you're using, that causes that error?

Comment: var http = require("http");
var ibmdb = require("ibm_db");

console.log("Test program to access DB2 sample database");


http.createServer(function (request, response) {


   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   
   response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8081);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');  It throws the above error whenever I include 'ibm_db'

Comment: I've added the above code to the post, for future readers.  As for the issue itself, it might be an issue with the version of Node.js you are running; see [this GitHub issue for `ibm_db`](https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/issues/102).

Comment: are you able to fix it? I am facing the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a 1 year old question but I think it requires at least one correct explanation/answer for that question here, so that future readers might not get confused.

> Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 47, got 46.

You will encounter with this error mostly on Windows platform, and this is actually not a bug or defect, this is simply because node-ibm_db does not support particular node version (which you are using for installing node-ibm_db on windows platform).

Reason: node-ibm_db provides pre-compiled node binaries within the module for particular main node-versions (like 4.x, 6.x etc),module do not compile at installing time (on windows only), it uses the pre-compiled binaries to installation and setup.

Hence if you use a latest major version of nodejs and specifically that,- which node-ibm_db is not supporting yet (or simply pre-compiled binaries are not available), you will get this error.